# Does puppet deploy the application through deplotit

Tags: puppet, deployit

I can able to see that xldeploy module in puppet supports

installation/service/configuration files for XL Deploy
xldeploy repository configuration items
xldeploy repository roles/permissions
xldeploy repository dictionaries
xldeploy cli installation
installs compatible java version (optional)

Link: https://github.com/xebialabs-community/puppet-xldeploy

How can i do a application deployment using puppet through deployit? or any other way to do it through automation?

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, the XL Deploy puppet plugin is meant to manage an XLD server installation. It is not a plugin that enabled deployments via puppet. The standard XL Deploy plugins do not provide this capability.

If you did want to trigger a puppet command to perform a deployment from within an XL Deploy deployment plan, I suggest you look into using rules (see https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/concept/getting-started-with-xl-deploy-rules.html).